# Remove Charles SSL root certificate from iPhone Simulators

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, charles-proxy

I installed Charles to debug HTTP communications on my iOS simulator. In the process in Charles I did: Menubar -> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles root certificate on iOS simulators.

Now I want to use the simulator normally but it only works if I have Charles running due to SSL failures. I tried reseting the simulator with: Menubar -> Simulator -> Reset content and settings... but it didn't help.

Is there a way to remove the installed Charles root certificate from the Simulators?

Answer (score 3):

Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings..
Erase all settings and content from your simulator including Charles root cert.